# Adding a Sprite Renderer

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I add a Sprite Renderer component in my gameobject, I get this error:

[image]

I want to have a Mesh Filter and "attach" a sprite on the GameObject in question.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mesh is a texture to place on top of something like a sprite. It seems like you're trying to create something that's already there. Try deleting "MeshFilter".
Or, you're adding the sprite to the wrong place. I'm not an expert on Unity. Also, this isn't c# related.